# "time saving" vs. "time savings"

Tags: grammar, nouns

Can "time saving" be a noun? In the following context, is it better to use "time saving" or "time savings"?

> In fact, many companies of our time do own the ability and strength to
> implement many projects together. When conducting projects together,
> **time saving** becomes practical.

> In fact, many companies of our time do own the ability and strength to
> implement many projects together. When conducting projects together,
> **time savings** become practical.

Comment: Note that "saving" is a verbal noun (gerund if you prefer), while "savings" is the plural of an actual, fully-functional noun (as when you talk about savings in the bank). I don't have strong feelings either way.

Comment: @Stuart F If conversion has occurred to allow the true plural-form noun 'savings', why can't the singular-form noun also have appeared? I'd say 'made various savings' is acceptable, showing a count usage of the plural form.

Answer (score 1):

Neither "time saving" nor "time savings" should be used as a noun in the mentioned paragraph.

Rather I would suggest "Conserving time" as a far better replacement.

"time management" will be the most perfect replacement though, but it is unclear if it can be used without having more context of the matter being spoken of.

Comment: You should explain why you consider "conserving time" is a far better replacement.